# wysihtml5 in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use a `wysihtml5` editor inside a modal. If I open the modal and only type in `textarea` and use fonts buttons then close the modal everything is good but if I try to insert a image, the editor open a modal inside the parent modal and then the parent modal with all body including the `wysihtml5` editor disappear.

Sometime occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined
```

Does anyone encountered the following problem? How can I solve it?

I am fetching the parent modal through ajax.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8a402d4j/11/

Comment: Hey, you have some code to demonstrate this ? try using jsfiddle.net to show us that problem! thx

Comment: I updated with jsfiddle.